# Issue running an app on a cloned AWS EC2 instance

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an application (php/node.js/mysql) running on a fully configured EC2 instance, using elastic beanstalk connected to an RDS DB. I tried to recreate that instance and run a test application and it didn't work, I though it might be something with the config of the instance, so I cloned the instance that is running correctly and tried to run the test app (which is exactly like the prod app) and I get this error: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

It has nothing to do with my internet connection, which is working fine. A couple of facts:

1- when I run the app on the instance I created, it does load the index.html page, but does not connect to any other page (this is a php/node.js/mysql app), and I get error 404.
2- when I try to load the url in the second (cloned) case, the subdomain I created, receives a www from the browser and gives me the error above. This could be some kind of wrong config on my godaddy, but it gives me no error when I try it on the created instance.

I'm having a hard time trying to figure this out, can someone shed some light pls?

Thanks all!